# Do I need to reset the loop in this code?

Tags: wp-reset-postdata

I use the code below, added to a template, to display random posts.

```
<ul>
<?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Do I need to reset, presumably by changing

```
<?php } ?>
```

to

```
<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And does the need to reset depend on whether this code-block is before or after other loops/queries in the template?

Answer (score 1):

**wp_reset_postdata()**

`wp_reset_postdata()` will restores the global $post variable to the current post in the main query. This is useful when using `WP_Query` to customize loops or create multiple loops on the same page.

[This Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) will solve all your queries about `wp_reset_postdata()` & `WP_Query` & `get_posts`

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you.